# Post 404 (Not Found) - Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm not sure why my post requests are not found?

I'm getting this error

Still getting this error no matter what I have tried and added to my posts im not sure if this is an axios thing or if my routes are actually incorrect please if you have any information about how to fix this or where I have gone wrong please help

```
xhr.js:177 POST https://enigmatic-cliffs-10818.herokuapp.com/api/user/register 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:177
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
```

I need help here is my register api with routes to allow people to register and login and ensure the user is authenticated. I have tried multiple solutions on multiple forums but It doesnt seem to fix or resolve anything

```
import axios from "axios";

class API {

    axios;

    constructor() {

        this.axios = axios.create();

    }

    /**
     * @param {String} name 
     * @param {String} value 
     */
    setHeader( name, value ) {

        if( value )

            this.axios.defaults.headers.common[name] = value;

        else

            delete this.axios.defaults.headers.common[name];

    }

    /**
     * @param {object} userData 
     * @param {String} userData.email
     * @param {String} userData.password
     * 
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    register( userData ) {
      console.log("------");
      console.log(userData);
      console.log("------");

        return axios.post("/api/user/register", userData);

    }


    /**
     * @param {object} userData 
     * @param {String} userData.email
     * @param {String} userData.password
     * 
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    login( userData ) {

        return axios.post("/api/user/login", userData);

    }

    authenticated() {

        return axios.post("/api/user/authenticated");

    }

}

export default new API();
```

I haven't found a solution for my application

Comment: Have you tried full URL? `return axios.post("https://enigmatic-cliffs-10818.herokuapp.com/api/user/register", userData);`

Comment: same error happens when adding the full url

Answer (score 0):

The cause for this 404 is in the [`index.js`](https://github.com/MarketingPlus/Tipsy/blob/a82b3ea6ee13952820eb7257f66bbb29e400092e/routes/index.js#L8) of the `routes` directory, when you declare `router.use("/api", /* .. */)` for the second time, the routes get overridden. This means, the only route associated with the `/api` endpoint is `/addFavorite/:id`.

```js
// These are your authentication routes.
router.use("/api", require("./authentication"));

//! These are your other `api` routes.
//! But this line will override the above routes.
//api routes
router.use("/api", apiRoutes);
```

To solve this, move `authentication.js` to `api` directory & make the following changes in `/api/index.js`.

```js
const router = require("express").Router();

const userRoutes = require("./user");
const authRoutes = require("./authentication");

router.use("/user", userRoutes);

//! Make sure to use the route as `/auth` to avoid collision,
//! since you have defined `/user/login` in the authentication module.
router.use("/auth", authRoutes);

module.exports = router;
```

By doing so, the authentication routes will be available at `/api/auth/user/login`.

Hence, you have to make authentication requests to the URL — [`https://enigmatic-cliffs-10818.herokuapp.com/api/auth/user/register`](https://enigmatic-cliffs-10818.herokuapp.com/api/auth/user/register).

Comment: thanks for your detailed response, I believe I have done everything you said correctly yet I'm still getting the same issues

Answer (score 0):

```
  fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Please use fetch function for your request.

Comment: I've tried this before and it results in a bigger error and my deployment fails